# My flutter/dart code is giving me a red NosuchmethodError:..The method 'toDouble'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to link the sign-up page, thats where its giving me the error of a red screen with NosuchmethodError:..The method 'toDouble'. I've been stuck on this for past 2 days, tried many things. I'm still learning so not a expert yet. I did go through the official documentation, but it was of no help. Its not working in the emulator.
Video for reference https://streamable.com/0qvcm5

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:morus/Screen/Login/login_screen.dart';
//import 'package:morus/Screen/Signup/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:morus/screen/complete_profile/sign_up/sign_up_screen.dart';
//import 'package:morus/screen/complete_profile/complete_profile_screen.dart';
import 'package:morus/screen/complete_profile/sign_up/sign_up_screen.dart';
import 'package:morus/Screen/Welcome/components/background.dart';
import 'package:morus/screen/components/rounded_button.dart';
import 'package:morus/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    // This size provide us total height and width of our screen
    return Background(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              "WELCOME TO Moe",
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
            SvgPicture.asset(
              "assets/icons/chat.svg",
              height: size.height * 0.45,
            ),
            SizedBox(height: size.height * 0.05),
            RoundedButton(
              text: "LOGIN",
              press: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) {
                      return LoginScreen();
                    },
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
            RoundedButton(
                text: "SIGN UP",
                color: kPrimaryLightColor,
                textColor: Colors.black,
                press: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return SignUpScreen();
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my sign_up_screen.dart

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'components/body.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static String routeName = "/sign_up";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Sign Up"),
      ),
      body: Body(),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my sign_up_form.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:morus/screen/components/custom_surfix_icon.dart';
import 'package:morus/screen/components/default_button.dart';
import 'package:morus/screen/components/form_error.dart';
import 'package:morus/screen/complete_profile/complete_profile_screen.dart';
//import 'package:shop_app/screens/login_success/login_success_screen.dart';

import '../../../../constants.dart';
import '../../../../size_config.dart';

class SignUpForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignUpFormState createState() => _SignUpFormState();
}

class _SignUpFormState extends State<SignUpForm> {
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email;
  String password;
  String conform_password;
  bool remember = false;
  final List<String> errors = [];

  void addError({String error}) {
    if (!errors.contains(error))
      setState(() {
        errors.add(error);
      });
  }

  void removeError({String error}) {
    if (errors.contains(error))
      setState(() {
        errors.remove(error);
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          buildEmailFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildPasswordFormField(),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(30)),
          buildConformPassFormField(),
          FormError(errors: errors),
          SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(40)),
          DefaultButton(
            text: "Continue",
            press: () {
              if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                _formKey.currentState.save();
                // if all are valid then go to success screen
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, CompleteProfileScreen.routeName);
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildConformPassFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => conform_password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPassNullError);
        } else if (value.isNotEmpty && password == conform_password) {
          removeError(error: kMatchPassError);
        }
        conform_password = value;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kPassNullError);
          return "";
        } else if ((password != value)) {
          addError(error: kMatchPassError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Confirm Password",
        hintText: "Re-enter your password",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Lock.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildPasswordFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      obscureText: true,
      onSaved: (newValue) => password = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kPassNullError);
        } else if (value.length >= 8) {
          removeError(error: kShortPassError);
        }
        password = value;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kPassNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (value.length < 8) {
          addError(error: kShortPassError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Password",
        hintText: "Enter your password",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Lock.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }

  TextFormField buildEmailFormField() {
    return TextFormField(
      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
      onSaved: (newValue) => email = newValue,
      onChanged: (value) {
        if (value.isNotEmpty) {
          removeError(error: kEmailNullError);
        } else if (emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          removeError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
        }
        return null;
      },
      validator: (value) {
        if (value.isEmpty) {
          addError(error: kEmailNullError);
          return "";
        } else if (!emailValidatorRegExp.hasMatch(value)) {
          addError(error: kInvalidEmailError);
          return "";
        }
        return null;
      },
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        labelText: "Email",
        hintText: "Enter your email",
        // If  you are using latest version of flutter then lable text and hint text shown like this
        // if you r using flutter less then 1.20.* then maybe this is not working properly
        floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
        suffixIcon: CustomSurffixIcon(svgIcon: "assets/icons/Mail.svg"),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the body.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:morus/screen/components/socal_card.dart';
import 'package:morus/constants.dart';
import 'package:morus/size_config.dart';

import 'sign_up_form.dart';

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: double.infinity,
        child: Padding(
          padding:
              EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.04), // 4%
                Text("Register Account", style: headingStyle),
                Text(
                  "Complete your details or continue \nwith social media",
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.08),
                SignUpForm(),
                SizedBox(height: SizeConfig.screenHeight * 0.08),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    SocalCard(
                      icon: "assets/icons/google-icon.svg",
                      press: () {},
                    ),
                    SocalCard(
                      icon: "assets/icons/facebook-2.svg",
                      press: () {},
                    ),
                    SocalCard(
                      icon: "assets/icons/twitter.svg",
                      press: () {},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenHeight(20)),
                Text(
                  'By continuing your confirm that you agree \nwith our Term and Condition',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my size_config.dart (it has the only mention of 'double')

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static double screenWidth;
  static double screenHeight;
  static double defaultSize;
  static Orientation orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  // 812 is the layout height that designer use
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}

// Get the proportionate height as per screen size
double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
  // 375 is the layout width that designer use
  return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Now, I can't even see anything related to `toDouble()` in the code you have provided.

Comment: console is showing no error, the error is popping up when I run the code and click(tap) the 'sign up' button. Instead of signup screen it show a red screen.

Comment: Post your `SignUpScreen()` code @Doctor

Comment: Could you also share your console output?

Comment: I checked around an toDouble() is a kotlin error

Comment: the below answer is correct  SizeConfig.init(context); had to be added before the widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Doctor based on your code I see that SizeConfig class has to be initialized before it is used. Try calling `SizeConfig.init(context);` before using it in your pages

Comment: is everything the same even after you called init ?

Comment: Tried it again, It worked. Thanks a lot. (sorry for the delay)